# Why to inflate layout into another layout in Android?

Tags: android

I'm new in Android development and I wanted to make application that has header, body and footer and by clicking on one of the buttons in footer some layout will be loaded into body. I used some kind of "MasterPage" as described [here](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx).
When the button is pressed neither `new_exercise` layout nor `exercises` layout is loaded. Why? Maybe instead of all of this I should use any kind of tabs? Or maybe I can't inflate layout and should create new activity?

Here the code of the BaseActivity and NewExercise activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{
    LinearLayout linBaseBody;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);

        linBaseBody = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.base_body);

        initButtons();
    }
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int id) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(id, linBaseBody);
    }

    private void initButtons()
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newEx);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  setContentView(R.layout.new_exercise);
              }
        });
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showAllEx);   
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  setContentView(R.layout.exercises);
              }
        });
    }

public class NewExercise extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.new_exercise);
    }
}
public class Exercises extends BaseActivity {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.exercises);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your code is written, it would make more sense to use a new Activity. However, If you wanted to keep all of the view in one Activity, you could walk through all of your layouts calling mLayout.setVisible(View.VISIBLE); or you could use ViewStubs.

As to answer your question, why, what you are doing is adding the view (and their layouts) directly to your already created and inflated content view (the one you created in onCreate). You will need to clear the Activities contentView first to see the changes you are making with the button.

Comment: Creating new activity on every click won't be too heavy or I should let to GC to worry about that?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are planning on doing in each of the Activities. But in all likely hood, no, it will not be too heavy on the GC, or more correctly, it shouldn't interfere with the user experience.

Comment: All I wanted to do is some kind of tabs(as I think about it now!) when each tab has different functionality, but all tabs will have the same header as described in my post. So will it be better to use `TabHost`(or something else?) instead of trying to inflate layout within one activity?

Comment: Yes, TabHost would be the easiest, prettiest and most efficient way.